# C# Get the name of an object without knowing its Type

Tags: c#, object, button, properties

```
private void function(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Is it possible to get the Name, without using a variable?

```
if(sender.getType().Name == "Button") {
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    ObjName = btn.Name
}

if(sender.getType().Name == "CheckBox") {
    CheckBox cbx= sender as CheckBox;
    ObjName = cbx.Name
}
```

I have a function that works with a lot of different object types, and the only thing I need is the Name.

Comment: My first thoughts are already shown in the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111512/c-sharp-finding-sender); you either need to switch through all known types, or cast to `dynamic` and hope nothing blows up at runtime.

Comment: if all objects are controls you can cast `sender` as `Control` since `Name` property is defined in `Control` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just cast it to its base type Control

```
var name = ((Control)sender).Name
```

Comment: `switch (((Control)ObjectList[i]).Name)...` That's Exactly what I wanted! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, if the base type is not the same you could you reflection as follows:

```
private  void function(object sender)
{
     if (sender != null && sender.GetType().GetProperty("Name") != null)
        {
            var val = sender.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(sender);
        } 
}
```

Comment: The reason I'm not a huge fan of this approach is that the function will bomb if the object passed does not have a `Name` property.

Comment: I tried that! But I was doing it wrong... Couldn't figure out the the GetValue property has to receive the object aswell :P by the way, it's `sender.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(sender, null)` @DangerZone on my case it always has a Name :)

Comment: The null check needs to be added to check if the name method exists.Tried out on console and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In the case where you can't use a common base type, such as if you are dealing with items from WinForms & WPF simultaneously, you can use reflection to check if the item has a name property, and then if it does return that value.

```
public string GetNameIfExists(dynamic item)
{
    if (item.GetType().GetProperty("Name") != null)
    {
        return item.Name;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This pattern is more common than checking the type name:

```
var btn = sender as button;
if (btn != null) // it's a button
{
    //...
    return;
}
var chkbx = sender as checkbox;
if (chkbx != null) // it's a checkbox
{
   //...
   return;
}
```

Comment: I was doing `switch(sender.getType().Name){case "button": **GetName** break; case "CheckBox": **GetName**...`. It's an ugly mess :P